# Get CefSharp Browser Popup Window from parent form

Tags: c#, browser, controls, cefsharp

I am using ChromiumWebBrowser(CefSharp) to load a website, When i click any link in the website, it open new popup window
I want to access ChromiumWebBrowser on new popup window but i do not know how do i can access it ?. Please can you them me

Thanks All

Comment: Which version are you using? And is it WPF or WinForms? Popup handling has changed a lot in recent versions.

Comment: Depends what your trying to do, getting a hold of the `IBrowser` instance for the `popup` maybe enough, please elaborate on what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @Yoshi: I am using CefSharp.WinForms.33.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version `43.0.0` now exposes a wrapper around the underlying `CefBrowser` (`IBrowser`), which allows you to perform browser related tasks (you can also get hold of the `HWND` for the created window if required).

Try implementing `ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated`, check the `IBrowser.IsPopup` property.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp/ILifeSpanHandler.cs#L48